# UIPicker selectRow not working - what's wrong with this code?

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I'm trying to set a default value for the UIPickerView. However, no matter which value I set it to, it always defaults to 1. The method below loads the picker just fine, and I can select it. So, what am I doing wrong? Here's the code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    arrayNo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [arrayNo addObject:@" 1 "];
    [arrayNo addObject:@" 2 "];
    [arrayNo addObject:@" 3 "];
    [arrayNo addObject:@" 4 "];
    [arrayNo addObject:@" 5 "];

    [pickerView selectRow:4 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
    mlabel.text= [arrayNo objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];    

}
```

Picker's DataSource methods:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    mlabel.text = [arrayNo objectAtIndex:row];
    NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

    [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

    NSNumber * myNumber = [f numberFromString:[arrayNo objectAtIndex:row]];

    [f release];

    prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSInteger myInteger = [myNumber integerValue];


    // save level
    [prefs setInteger:myInteger forKey:@"myInt"];

    // saving it all
    [prefs synchronize];


}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
    return [arrayNo count];
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works if I put it in this method:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear: (BOOL) animated
```

Answer (score 7):

You might need to call `reloadAllComponents` after populating the array and before trying to select the row. The picker may not know your new number of elements yet.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is to delegate the `didSelectRow` call:

```
self.pickerView.delegate?.pickerView?(self.providerPickerView, didSelectRow: 0, inComponent: 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do following steps

- load array before picker initializing..
- call [pickerView selectRow:4 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
- call [pickerView reloadAllComponents];

In recent apple release notes apples says "In iOS 5.0 UIPickerView doesn’t send its pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent: delegate message due to a programatic selection." So we need call relaodAppComponents forcefully..

Give acknowledge if its work...

Answer (score 1):

This is because you need to set the the data source in viewdidload otherwise if you set it from the storyboard, it will be loaded after viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 0):

- we can't see how you setup the datasource for the picker
- you do an animated selectRow in viewDidLoad (this view isn't on screen yet ...)

Have you tried with animated:NO ?

Answer (score 0):

What does arrayNo do? Is it being used to populate the UIPickerView? If so, you will have to `[pickerView reloadAllComponents]` before calling `selectRow:inComponent:animated:`

Answer (score -1):

You need call reloadComponent to update picker before

Swift

```
self.picker.reloadComponent(0)
self.picker.selectRow(arrayData.count - 1, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
```